# ASP.NET MVC Areas with angularJS app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

How to use AngularJS framework with Asp.net MVC "Areas"?

I am developing an application with having large user base and large database tables (i.e. around 5 Millions of row for 8/10 tables). So, I had plan to use AngularJS for handling data manipulation and UI (within .cshtml page). I had a knowledge on how to develop Asp.net MVC web application with AngularJS app, but my application has multiple Asp.net MVC "Areas". I am using asp.net MVC5. I have a following questions.

1. Is it good to have a AngularJS framework for my application requirement?
2. What is the efficient way to use AngularJS framework with Asp.net MVC "Areas"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with large datasets, as per suggestions found below ReactJS would be a good fit.

If you have to choose AngularJS because of its full stack of functionality available in the framework, you may very well go with isolated mini SPAs in your areas
Links:
http://blog.backand.com/angularjs-vs-react/

https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/reactjs-vs-angular-js-performance-comparison-knockout